# How to make sure that firewall is off?

Tags: 14.04

I'm new  to Ubuntu. I want to turn off firewall and make sure that it's turned off and want to turn off iptables.

```
iptables:
  Installed: 1.4.21-1ubuntu1
  Candidate: 1.4.21-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 1.4.21-1ubuntu1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status


Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destinat
```

Comment: Did you install iptables manually?

Comment: If not then to disable firewall completely do: `sudo ufw disable` . To check status do: `sudo ufw status`

Comment: thanks for replying , i want to check if iptables are installed or not , how can i check it ?

Comment: `apt-cache policy iptables`

Comment: It is installed

Comment: @Raphael if you need more then I have in the answer please leave a comment ;-)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
```

You can turn it off and on with ...

```
sudo ufw disable
sudo ufw enable
```

By default it is disabled.

---

You can check if there are iptables rules active with:

```
sudo iptables -L
```

Your output, with no lines between the `target     prot opt source               destination` header and the next `Chain`, indicates that no rules are active.

If you have `iptables` active this will cancel it

```
sudo iptables -X
sudo iptables -t nat -F
sudo iptables -t nat -X
sudo iptables -t mangle -F
sudo iptables -t mangle -X
sudo iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
sudo iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

- [explanation of all the options](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables.man.html)

---

If you want a graphical method:

```
sudo apt-get install gufw
```

- [Website](http://gufw.org/)
- Image:

[image]

Comment: Thanks , i tried firewall now and it's inactive so it's disabled , but iptables i want to check if it's installed ot not , and where can i find it ?

Comment: installed does not mean rules active ;-) iptables -L to see if there are any rules.

Comment: i edited post with result

Comment: That result in your edit means there are NO rules active ;)

Comment: do you mean beacuse target and source is empty ?

Comment: yeah you would have seen lines with port numbers and things like that if it was active ;-)

Comment: when i run "service ufw disable", it says ufw - unrecognized service. But "service ufw start", "service ufw stop" run ok. What would be the reason?